# Add a tooltip to an ExtJS checkcolumn

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJS `checkcolumn` in a `Ext.tree.Panel`:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'enabled',
    hideable: true,
    stateId: 'enabledColumn',
    width: 30,
    listeners: {
        checkchange: function (grid, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
            var tree = grid.up('processtree');
            tree.getController().onCheckChange(tree, rowIndex, checked);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add a `tooltip` to this, in a similar style to other columns in the same grid, i.e.

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 30,
    hideable: false,
    stateId: 'deleteColumn',
    items: [{
        icon: 'images/delete2.png',
        tooltip: 'Delete',
        handler: 'onDelete'
    }]
}
```

The documentation, however, is vague on its implementation other than stating a tooltip is available for the column header, which is undesirable as the other tooltips on the page occur on items within their respective columns.

How can I apply a tooltip of a similar style to the other columns? given that all code is split into separate files, will this tooltip have to be a separate entity (separate file and listed in the `Ext.tree.Panel`'s `requires`)?

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right, you want to display a tooltip on each item from the column. To do that, you can use a rendered for the column you want like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record, row, col) {
        meta['tdAttr'] = 'data-qtip="the tooltip for ' + value + '"';
        return whatYouWantToDisplayInThatColumnsCell;
    }
}
```

For checkcolumn:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record, row, col) {
        meta['tdAttr'] = 'data-qtip="the tooltip for ' + value + '"';
        return new Ext.ux.CheckColumn().renderer(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The renderer applies a tooltip as desired, but the content (the checkbox) doesn't render in the checkcolumn; I've tried returning different values, but to no avail. What needs to be returned for a checkcolumn in order to render correctly, given this renderer is applied?